# Does a Wireless Access Point (WAP) connect to a router or to a modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

Please note that I have read [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/169426/differences-between-a-modem-a-wireless-access-point-and-a-router) on the site, but the answer provided did not address my confusion, and I'd just like to clarify some of the terminology.

I understand that a Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN) lets computers connect to that network wirelessly, without a physical cable connecting the computers to the router. And to do so, the computers need to connect to a Wireless Access Point (WAP).

I suspect that a WAP connects to a **router**, not a modem; that's in fact what the top answer of the linked post says. But the following diagram, taken from [this website](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/WLAN-vs-Ethernet-LAN.html), seems to suggest a WAP is hardwired to a modem. And it labeled the WAP as a WLAN router.

[image]

Is there no single answer? Can a WAP connect to a router and/or a modem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wireless Access Point acts as a *point* where wireless clients can gain *access* to whatever kind of network you want to let your wireless clients have access to. The IEEE 802.11 spec doesn’t require the underlying network to be Ethernet, but that’s by far the most common.

What other kinds of middleboxes (network infrastructure equipment) make up that network is not specified by the standard.

You can connect an AP to a transceiver, repeater, hub, bridge, switch, router, gateway, firewall, modem, a WDS wireless bridge, some kind of wireless mesh node, CSU/DSU, etc. etc. … whatever makes sense for the kind of network you’re trying to build.

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind: are WAPs used only for WLAN networks, or can they be used for WAN networks as well?

Comment: The WWAN equivent of an AP is called a BTS (Base Transceiver Station) a.k.a. a “cell tower”.